# Python : (Titanic) debugging error in imputing fare

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging

I will thank very much for your help.I have a problem with the classic Kaggle Titanic Tutorial for machine learning. My problem is when using a pivotal table to imput means in a dataframe (or tupple):

```
fare_means = df.pivot_table("Fare", index= "Pclass", aggfunc="mean")

​fare_means.info()    
fare_class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>    
Int64   
Index: 3 entries, 1 to 3    
Data columns (total 1 columns):  Fare    3 non-null float64  
dtypes: float64(1)   
memory usage: 48.0 bytes

fare_means   
Out[46]:   
Fare ---Pclass     
1     ------- 84.154687  
2      -------20.662183   
3      -------13.675550

df_test['Fare'] = df_test[['Fare', 'Pclass']].apply(lambda x:

fare_means[x['Pclass']] if pd.isnull(x['Fare'])

else x['Fare'], axis=1)
```

## KeyError: (3, u'occurred at index 152')

```
df_test.iloc[150:155, 0: ]   
  Index-- Pclass    ----    Fare       
  150 ------ 1      --------83.1583   
  151 ------ 3      --------7.8958    
  152 ------ 3      --------NaN    
  153 ------ 3      --------12.1833  
  154 ------ 3      --------31.3875
```

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted  it out, the problem is that a pivotal table needs to be indexed like this

```
`import pandas 
train = pd.read_csv('.../kaggletrain')

test =  pd.read_csv('.../kaggletest')

fare_means = train.pivot_table('Fare', index = 'Pclass', aggfunc = 'mean')

fare_means[1:2]

therefore 

test['Fare'] = test[['Fare','Pclass']].apply(lambda x:
                                             fare_means[int(x['Pclass']-1):int(x['Pclass'])] if pd.isnull(x['Fare'])
                                             else x['Fare'], axis=1)`
```